# Will PM2 work with Node.js net API?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, pm2

### Background

I need to make a server app that listens to several TCP connections. This app must be lightweight and the TCP connections will come from GPS devices ( not from browsers, so I can't use WebSockets for example ).

### Research

To make sure this scales properly to thousands of devices I need to take full advantage of all the machines CPUs. According to my research I found 2 ways of doing it:

1. Create a [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) server and use the native [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) API Node.js provides
2. Create an app and use PM2 to "fork" it across all CPUs

According to my understanding, these options are mutually exclusive. If I choose option 1, I can't use PM2, and vice-versa.

### Problem

My team uses PM2 everywhere, so for consistency sake I would like to use PM2 as well. The problem here is that PM2 has issues with Node.js socket applications. I know for instance that to use `socket.io` we need to install extra modules ( `sticky-session` ) but since I am using the native API there is no information 
 on what adaptations I need to do whatsoever.

Using the Native `net` API I have no idea if PM2 will distribute the connections evenly among the CPUs nor can I find any information if the data will go to the right worker when the time comes.

### Code

To demonstrate my objective I made a small app using  the  `cluster` native Node.js API:

```
const cluster = require("cluster");
const net = require("net");
const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });

} else {
    // Workers can share any TCP connection
    const server = net.createServer( connection => {
        console.log(`Client connected to ${process.pid}`);
        connection.on( "end", () => console.log( `Client disconnected from ${process.pid}` ) );
        connection.on( "data", data =>console.log(`${process.pid} received ${data.toString("ascii")}`) );
        connection.on( "close", () => console.log(`Client closed connection with ${process.pid}`) );
    } );

    server.listen( 8124, () => console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} Bound`) );

    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

According to what I understand of the documentation, this sever balances load through all the CPUs and redirects the connections as well.

You can try this example using telnet: `telnet localhost 8124`

### Questions

1. Is this behavior possible with PM2? If so How ( What would the code look like )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

So, the answer here is tricky ...

### How PM2 cluster works

So, PM2 cluster mode actually uses the Node.js native API. This means that using the `net` and `cluster` native APIs from Node would pretty much just be replicating work already done by PM2, unless you want to do it in a radically different way.

### Will PM2 cluster work properly with sockets?

PM2 will scale correctly using the `cluster` functionality ( what I refer to as "fork" the app using PM2 ) provided that your application is **stateless**.

If it is not, PM2 cannot guarantee anything.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#statelessify-your-application

### Conclusion

Yes, but your app needs to be stateless.
You need to save your socket connections and what be in Redis or MongoDB or something else.