# How to store a Net socket to a database in order to keep a node js app stateless?

Tags: node.js, sockets, cluster-computing, pm2

My application is using `Net` API (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) sockets and accept connections from clients that cannot use any other way to communicate than raw TCP sockets.

I'm trying to use `pm2` with my app and clusterize it on all my cpus. Unfortunately this does not work since one process cannot use the in-memory stored sockets from any of the other processes.

I'm looking for a way to save each connections to a database, even an in-memory store would fit my needs for as long as i can call it and use it again from any other process.

Somebody else asked pretty much the same question here he was told that he should just use Redis to store the sockets. But the guy who answered apparently had no idea how to do that.

Question was asked here: [Will PM2 work with Node.js net API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102382/will-pm2-work-with-node-js-net-api)

My question is how could i do that ?

Actually i think this is just impossible. What i really need is a way to "recreate" the socket object through it's file descriptor number that could be save as an integer in the database, but again, this is getting really tricky. I'm kind of stuck here. Documentation says nothing about it.

Maybe there's another way to keep my app stateless ?

Thanks a lot for reading, i'll be glad if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no methods to save a special type that is a resource.

In the database you can save the way how to re-created it (re-opene).

But I think that in your situation, a better solution will be to add an extra layer that will provide communication with a descriptor and all elements of the cluster. In the option you have: *exchange events between node process* or *WebSockets*.

Comment: Yes, i thought about exchanging events between processes. That could be my solution. However, i don't really understand what you meant here "In the database you can save the way how to re-created it (re-opene)." Can you please explain a little more ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is sharing file descriptors by passing them between the server processes using a Unix domain socket. Have a look at the [usocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usocket) package which implements passing file descriptors for Node.js.

Comment: This one is very interesting as well. I will look into it. Thanks a lot !